# Git clone Heroku app

Tags: git, heroku, github, git-clone

How can I use git clone for **someone else's** Heroku app? All I can find is on your own Heroku app. Reason I want to do this is that I am using a boilerplate code for part of my app but the github repo is out of date and doesn't work but the linked demo on Heroku does work fine. I just need to see the routes for stripe actions.

Comment: It is possible they deployed a fork or separate branch. Open an issue in the repository and ask where the latest deployed code exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only clone an app for which you have access to. And only the app owner can give you access to that app.

```
heroku access:add <email address> -a <app name>
```

You will then have access to both push and pull the code, and will be able to clone from that app.
Apps for which you don't have access to cannot be cloned.

Comment: Is there anyway of seeing the backend code? I hate that the demo works and the Github fails so badly.

Comment: No. If you were able to do so for one app, you'd be able to do so for all of them, which would be a huge security issue.